# Looking for Interactive floor plan editor/creator JavaScript

Tags: javascript, web

I am looking for a JS library for a project that is going to be used to design Floor Layouts. I have been experimenting with Fabric.js but since it is low level, every functionality needs to be designed from the ground up.

Some functionalities I want to have, are:

- Movement by grid-steps (snap to grid).
- Snap to object (prevent overlapping).
- Object tooltips.
- Pan, Zoom, Group functionalities.

I am looking for preferably open-source or a reasonably priced library.

Comment: We aready have 6 questions about [floorplan](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/search?q=floorplan). Maybe there will be some help there? I hope that you get a good answer, as I am interested in this too :-) If you find something somewhere else, please post an answer here. Thanks

Comment: @Mawg In a comment in one of the posts you linked I found [InteractJS](https://interactjs.io/) which might be able to be worked better as it manipulates html elements. Thank you for the information and your time.

Comment: Let me know if you don't find anything better & I will post that as an answer, in order to help others who might read this question in future. Good luck, and please, please, please, if you open source your code, let us know about it :-)

Comment: After working with interactJS for a few days now I have seen some pretty massive limitations to what it can do compared to what I need it for, so I have jumped back into FabricJS. If you invest a good amount of time in it, it will do what you want it.

As of now this question is still not answered.